# Seemingly Impossible output of Linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have a function that takes a word as input and adds a struct containing that word to the end of a list of linked structs, each of which contain a word and a pointer to the next struct ('node'). But I'm getting a weird output which as far as i can tell should be impossible (but obviously isn't).

Function

```
void push(char* word) {
    if(first == NULL){         // if runs first time push is called
        first = malloc(46);
        first->next = NULL;
    }
    printf("first->str = %s\n", first->str);
    struct node *current = first;         //start at beginning of linked list
    while(current->next != NULL)          //find the last 'link' 
    {
        printf("running while");
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->str = word;                  
    current->next = malloc(46);
    current->next->next = NULL;
    printf("first->str after = %s\n", first->str);
    printf("current->str after = %s\n", current->str);
}
```

the struct is

```
struct node {
    char* str;
    struct node* next;
};
```

`first` is declared globally as:

```
struct node *first = NULL;
```

Output

```
first->str = (null)
first->str after = hello
current->str after = hello             //current->str = first->str
first->str = world                    // <-this should not happen
running While
first->str after = world             
current->str after = world            //current-str = first->next->str
world
world
(null)
```

I call this function then get another word and call it again. Here the first word is 'hello' and the second is 'world'. My question is how is world being assigned to first->str when no assignment to either struct has been made with 'world'. In fact **nothing** has been done to either struct between the end of the last call of push and the beginning of the second call of push, and yet first->str changed from 'hello' to 'world'.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me the code you're using to send values to `push` is using the *same* buffer for each send, so each node gets the same `char*` due to `current->str = word`, and thus reference the same data; the last thing you read. And related, there are *much* easier ways to push to the end (or beginning) of a linked list

Comment: you don't want to specify 46 as the number of bytes to allocate.  You should use the `sizeof` operator with struct.  For example, `first = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`.  It's hard to imagine that the size of a node struct is really 46 bytes.

Comment: so `char*` is a pointer to the memory where `word` is held, And when i assign `word` to `first->str` with `current->str = word` it just points `first->str` to the memory where `word` is held? Then is doesn't take the array that `word` points to and putt it in the memory that `first->str` points to? If so i see whats this is happening. @WhozCraig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `current->str = strdup(word)` instead of `current->str = word`; don't forget to free `node->str` when destroying `node`.